# OpenGL GLfloat not recognized Java

Tags: java, opengl, compiler-errors, opengl-2.0

I tried to create a GLfloat buffer array with

`GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { .2f, .2f, .6f, 1f };`

But java can not find class `GLfloat` and when I try to use a normal float array I get an error with this line

`gl.glMaterialfv(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);`

Error reads `incompatible types: float[] cannot be converted to FloatBuffer`

Is there a special way to create a `GLfloat` or is there something that I need to import from openGL to make this work?

Comment: Is this LWJGL?  You should probably ask on their forum.  I think they use `float` instead of the GL version in Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution I found for this was to use a float array

`float mat_diffuse[] = { .2f, .2f, .6f, 1f };`

and then changed

`gl.glMaterialfv(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);`

to

`gl.glMaterialfv(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse, 0);`

not sure why it worked, but it did.

Comment: A [`FloatBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html) is a special NIO buffer used for moving memory around quickly (ideally by not moving it, but rather allocating it in the desired areas) and accessing the values with the correct byte-endianness.  You can construct a `FloatBuffer` from a `float[]`, but they are different animals.

Comment: UNfortunately it doesn't work always as intended https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67298120/loading-generated-texture-data-is-inconclusive-in-libgdx-lwjgl